# Setting the Cursor Position

Tags: java, android, libgdx

So I have a game I am working on and once you finish playing I want to be able for the user to tap on the "Play Again" button and be able to reset at the start. 
To do this I create a Rectangle over the Texture and use the contains() method.

```
if(cloud.contains((float)Gdx.input.getX(),(float)(Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY()))){
    reset();
}
```

Reset method:

```
public void reset(){
    speed=0;
    paraY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - para[parachuteState].getHeight();
    gameState=0;
    backY = 0-Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    bach=0;
    Gdx.input.setCursorPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2,Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
}
```

So what is happening is the program recognizes the button being pressed and resets but when the game is over again it automatically resets without displaying the end screen. I think that the cursor is not being moved to the center and is instead remaining on top of the button. Am I incorrectly using the setCursorPosition() method or is there another way to do this?

Comment: But why don't you want to use Button instead of Texture with Rectangle?

Comment: Read up on touch listeners. It looks like you are continuously polling the last known finger position instead of reacting to new taps on the screen. `setCursorPosition` affects where the arrow is on a PC. It doesn't do anything on Android because there is no cursor.

Comment: Would a button be easier? I have an image I drew in Adobe Illustrator that I want to be clickable @Enigo

Comment: Also thanks for the information I'll learn about touch listeners @Tenfour04

Comment: @ThomasS. see my answer. Feel free to ask if you have any questions :)

Answer (score 0):

The button would be just right. It might looks more complex, but it's recommended way to do what you want to do. 
So, to create a button you should do something like this:

```
Skin skin = new Skin();
skin.addRegions(uiTextureAtlas);
TextButton.TextButtonStyle buttonStyle = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
buttonStyle.up = skin.getDrawable("textureName");
buttonStyle.font = font;
Button button = new Button(buttonStyle);
button.addListener(new InputListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        reset();
        return true;
    }
});
button.setSize(100, 100);
button.setPosition(300, 400);
```

then in your Screen class you create

```
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.addActor(button);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
```